# multiprocessing Pool slower with method than function

Tags: python

I tried to get image binary from url by using requests or urllib

Code looks like this:

```py
class Myclass:
  def __init__(self, image_list)
    self.__image_list = image_list
   
  def run(self, image_list):
    pool = Pool(30)
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(self.get_from_url, self.__image_list):
      pass

  def get_from_url(self, image_list):
    #codes of HTTP request(either using requests or urllib)
```

It turns out to be too slow with this code.

But when I move in-class method(get_from_url) to outside of class it works fine:

```py
def get_from_url(image_list):
  #codes of HTTP request(either using requests or urllib)

class Myclass:
  def __init__(self, image_list)
    self.__image_list = image_list
   
  def run(self, image_list):
    pool = Pool(30)
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(get_from_url, self.__image_list):
      pass
```

What is difference between these approaches and why is one slower than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first case, `get_from_url` is a non-static method on `Myclass`. For this to be called asynchronously, the entire class (with all its attributes, like the whole of `self.__image_list`) needs to be pickled and sent to the new process and then unpickled in the new process.

In the second case, the function is not tied to a class so the only item that is transferred to the Pool's process is the argument(s) for `get_from_url`.

You could define `get_from_url` as a `@staticmethod` to keep it within the class but prevent the whole of `self` being pickled:

```py
class Myclass:
  def __init__(self, image_list):
    self.__image_list = image_list
   
  def run(self, image_list):
    pool = Pool(30)
    for _ in pool.imap_unordered(self.get_from_url, self.__image_list):
      pass

  @staticmethod
  def get_from_url(image_list):
    #codes of HTTP request(either using requests or urllib)
```